# How to share data between an iOS app and a macOS app?

Tags: ios, macos

I have an iOS app that plays music with the MusicKit API. I want to write a companion app for macOS that communicates with the iOS app.

For example, my iPhone is playing music. When a new track starts playing, a notification appears in the macOS app. I can click a button on macOS to skip to the next track on my phone.

What's the best way to communicate between devices like this?

I think there are two important use cases:

1. For static data like account details and preferences.
2. For real-time messages.

I could do everything via a remote server but I wonder if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to have your app installed on iOS and macOS and needs to separately grant permission to receive push notifications.

Keep in mind that Apple does not guarantee the real-time delivery or delivery at all of remote push notifications. Remote push notifications may also be discarded by the APNS if many are sent within a short timeframe. It is not recommended to use the APNS for user-initiated actions such as music track controlling, as the user expects an (immediate) result. A web socket or other permanent connection between your server and its clients should be used instead.

**Playing music on one device, stopping on another:**

1. Request permission to send remote push notifications to get the unique APNS token for each device.
2. Store the device tokens on your server.
3. Make the iOS client notify the server that the user started playing music.
4. Make the server send a remote push notification to the macOS client via the APNS.
5. On the macOS client handle the user interaction with the push notification and report the user action back to the server.
6. Make the server notify the iOS of the user interaction via a web socket connection, rather than a remote push notification to ensure that the client handles the user action.
7. Make the iOS client skip the track.

**Synching user preferences:**

1. Store preferences on server for every change.
2. Request preferences from server on every app launch or dynamically when the preferences change by triggering the request through a remote push notification by the server or via a web socket connection, depending on how real-time the synchronization should be.

Comment: Are there any options to, for example, share iCloud data between an iOS app and a macOS app?

Comment: @KevinLawrence, yes, iCloud key-value storage can be used to store your preferences. You would share a common iCloud container for the iOS and macOS app. Any changes by one client get pushed to other clients. But again, Apple does not guarantee real-time synching between the iCloud and local storage. Depending on your business you may want to store preferences on your server, e.g. if you offer your app also outside Apple’s ecosystem, e.g. Android which doesn’t have iCloud access, or you want to run analytics over user preferences, or trigger workflows on your server on preference change.